# Does paypal sdk 2.0.2 support peer to peer adaptive payment?

Tags: paypal

I am using the Classic API SDK to allow one paypal user to pay another paypal user

in the latest Paypal SDK 2.0.2 (not Classic API)
does it allow for peer to peer adaptive payment yet?

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

Answer (score 0):

The sdk does not yet support peer to peer adaptive payments, although this is a feature that would be addressed in a future release.